# Flex vs. JQuery for Drag-n-Drop Interface

Tags: jquery, apache-flex

I'm developing an application that will randomize a list of words, and display them to the user.  The user will then be able to drag the box containing each word over a Cartesian plane, and drop it anywhere they like.  They will also be able to link various words together on the same plane.  Once a user has completed these tasks, I want to update a database with that user's data - the coordinates of each word, as well as any parent words that may exist for each word.

I started developing the application in Flex, but I'm running into problems integrating the data manipulation.  It might just be me, but I find the way Flex is structured to be very counter-intuitive.  I'm playing around with shifting the project over to perhaps a JQuery build.

I'm proficient in neither JQuery nor Flex, however, and I'm not sure which one will be easier to pick up and develop a working prototype with.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you start here a bit with the Flash vs HTML5 war.
You could use  HTML/Javascript. 
[jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com) has functionality for drag and drop. Head over to the [demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) to see some demos and instructions on how to implement it.
Positioning is nicely build in jQuery and has a nice library in jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

I hope those are enough starters to get you building your first prototype.